# paddle code runtime error (PreconditionNotMet)

Tags: python-3.x, paddle-paddle

RuntimeError: (PreconditionNotMet) The third-party dynamic library (cublas64_102.dll;cublas64_10.dll) that Paddle depends on is not configured correctly. (error code is 126)
Suggestions:

1. Check if the third-party dynamic library (e.g. CUDA, CUDNN) is installed correctly and its version is matched with paddlepaddle you installed.
2. Configure third-party dynamic library environment variables as follows:

- Linux: set LD_LIBRARY_PATH by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`
- Windows: set PATH by `set PATH=XXX; (at C:\home\workspace\Paddle_release\paddle\fluid\platform\dynload\dynamic_loader.cc:265)

my system cuda version is below:

```
!nvcc  --version
```

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:04_Central_Daylight_Time_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

I have reinstalled my cuda from 11.5 to 10.0 still not been able to run the paddle code. Please advise

Comment: "and its version is matched with paddlepaddle you installed."  Your paddlepaddle is expecting "cublas64_102.dll;"  That is from CUDA 10.2, not CUDA 10.0.  You cannot use CUDA 10.0 as a replacement or substitute for CUDA 10.2

Comment: okay let me reinstall my cuda with 10.2

Comment: Now i am receiving new cuda errors:
**ExternalError:  Cudnn error, CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM  (at C:/home/workspace/Paddle_release/paddle/fluid/operators/batch_norm_op.cu:372)
      [operator < batch_norm > error]**